# XML parsing using BeautifulSoup : retrieve multiple text contents with same id inside same document

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve multiple text contents with the same doc number inside a single document ( tag)

My XML file looks like this :

```
<doc>
<docnum>1234</docnum>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
<docdesc>only text</docdesc>
</doc>

<doc>
<docnum>789</docnum>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
<docdesc>only and only texts</docdesc>
</doc>
```

But BeautifulSoup's find_all() and find() methods cannot extract them individually.
My code snippet is as follows :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('file.xml', 'r') as openfile:
    content = "".join(openfile.readlines())
    soupcontent = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    docnums = [str(t.text) for t in (soupcontent.findAll('docnum'))]
    doctexts = [str(t.text) for t in (soupcontent.find_all('p'))]
    for a, b in zip(docnums, doctexts):
        print(a + '\n' + b)
```

But instead of matching docnum of doc1 with all the p of doc1, it is matching everything.
Nested for loops within each find_all() also does not help. It fails to stop when the end of doc tag is reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will print all `<docnum>`, `<p>` and `<docdesc>` for each individual `<doc>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<doc>
<docnum>1234</docnum>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
<docdesc>only text</docdesc>
</doc>

<doc>
<docnum>789</docnum>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
<docdesc>only and only texts</docdesc>
</doc>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for doc in soup.select('doc'):
    print('docnum :', doc.docnum.text)
    print('text   :', [p.text for p in doc.select('p')])
    print('docdesc:', doc.docdesc.text)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
docnum : 1234
text   : ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5']
docdesc: only text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docnum : 789
text   : ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5']
docdesc: only and only texts
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

EDIT: To store data in lists, you can do:

```
docnums   = []
doctexts  = []

for doc in soup.select('doc'):
    docnums.append(doc.docnum.text)
    doctexts.append([p.text for p in doc.select('p')])

for n, t in zip(docnums, doctexts):
    print(n)
    print(' '.join(t))
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej. Just a small question, if the tag name inside the doc is <text> then will the attribute .text work?